# disable web.config in iis7 / php

Tags: php, iis-7

I'm getting startup errors (500) in IIS7 running PHP-applications.

Setting system.webServer/httpErrors to *detailed* explains the problem:

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070005
Config Error    Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File \\?\C:\opt\php\public\web.config
```

Adding web.config to the public dir doesn't help, in fact it gets worse,
without file, just startup error, with file persistant error.

iusr has permission to dir & file, tried with dummy contents in webconfig.

No .NET / .ASP on server - only PHP. Thankful for any hints for an easy fix.

Comment: Ok, i changed account for application pools to "local system" and everything's working. Is this ugly?